# Prism Template Pack 2.0, IllegalArgumentException

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, prism

An error occurs when building with *Prism Template Pack 2.0*.

I created a project of Xamarin.Forms (Android / iOS).
Next, I installed `Xam.Plugin.Media using NuGet`.
And when I ran the build, I get an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added`.

In order to avoid this error, I attempted to modify the packages.config file, but the file does not exist anywhere.
(In the case of Prism Template Pack 1.x, problems could be avoided by modifying the packages.config file)

How can I avoid the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Prism Template Pack 2.0 is using the new .NET Standard based project system.  This means that there is no more packages.config.  The Nugets are defined within the csproj file of the project.  You also do not need to add the Nuget packages to every project in the solution.  Just add it to the main XF project and the Android/iOS projects will inherit the NuGet references automatically.

Comment: Thanks Brian.
This error occurs when multiple versions of the same support library are registered in the project.
However, support libraries are not written in the csproj file of the main project.
Where is the version of the support library used in the project?

Comment: **Error:**
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;

Comment: **[Main project .csproj file]:**
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Media" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="2.4.0.74863" />
    <PackageReference Include="Prism.Unity.Forms" Version="7.0.0.168-pre" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Comment: They are inherited from the main XF project.  You could try adding them to the Android project directly and see if that helps at all.

Comment: You can also try deleting your obj and bin folder for each project